# In Java 128bit hash where 32bit (13 digits) would be epoch and remaining digit (86bit) some hash value

Tags: java, oracle, hashcode, hash-function

In Java 128bit hash where 32bit (13 digits) would be epoch and remaining digit (86 bit)  some hash value

```
input -> string some random string of n size=
output-> 128bit or 38 digits number

39 digits(128 bits)=       epoch +some hashvalue
                    1475166540000+*************************
```

Could anyone suggest some hash function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that 128 bits is not 39 digits, but only 4. If you're willing to change the length of the hash, you can do something like this (total 344 bits):

```
String input = "abcdef";
String output = null;

try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] hash = digest.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    output = System.currentTimeMillis() + new String(hash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(output);  // Your new hash
```

Comment: I want to create a 38digit Number(128bits) which will be stored in Oracle Number datatype and the epoch number component would act as a trailing number, where I want to query with epochs. i.e between two epoch numbers.